# Multiprocessing access large shared read-only DataFrame, aggregate outputs

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I'm having some trouble figuring out how to use multiprocessing in my current workflow - there are lots of examples, some of which are old and some of which are outdated.

I'm on windows 10, python 3.7

**Problem:**
I have a large DataFrame of historical records (called source_df), and another DataFrame of new records (called new_df). For each record in new_df, I want to find the "best match" in source_df based on a number of criteria.

**Pseudo code**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from multiprocessing import Pool, Manager, Process

# existing records- a record ID and multiple defining features. Millions of recs in practice
source_df = pd.DataFrame([['A',1,2,'foo'],['B',3,7,'bar'],['C',2,6,'baz'],['D',6,2,'green'],['E',2,5,'red']],columns = ['rec_id','feature1','feature2','feature3'])

# new records- a record ID and multiple defining features
new_df = pd.DataFrame([['F',1,2,'foo'],['G',3,7,'bar'],['H',9,3,'zebra']],columns = ['rec_id','feature1','feature2','feature3'])

new_recs = #CONVERT new_df into format suitable to for submitting to multiprocessing (numpy array?)

def find_rec(new_rec):
    #some function to take 1 record from new_df and find best match in manager.gsource.
    
    return (new_rec['rec_id'],matched_rec_id) #return the rec ID from new_df and the rec_id it matched to (if no suitable match, will be null)

manager = Manager()
manager.gsource = #CONVERT source_df into (array? raw_array?) format that can be globally accessed (READ ONLY) by workers

pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=4)
result = pool.starmap(my_func,new_recs)

print(result)

[('F','A'),('G','B'),('H',None)] #desired result
```

The key is I want to make sure source_df (and whatever shared memory version of it is created) don't duplicate for every process.

Any guidance would be appreciated!